# How to transfer all conda environments to new computer

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Is it possible to transfer all of my individual conda environments to a file, where each environment lists the packages, and then I can rebuild all of the environments at once on the new machine?

There are many similar questions on here, but commands such as `conda list --export > package-list.txt` just list every package in all of the environments. I could build a file environment-by-environment using `conda env export > environment.yml`, but would prefer to avoid that.

Is there a way to create a file that would look something like the below, that would then recreate each environment?

```
name: ckcviz
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - abseil-cpp=20230802.0=h61975a4_2
  - altair=5.0.1=py311hecd8cb5_0
  - anyio=4.2.0=py311hecd8cb5_0
name: env2
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - abseil-cpp=20230802.0=h61975a4_2
  - blas=1.0=openblas
  - bleach=4.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
```

Comment: as far as I am aware, you'd have to do something like `conda env export > environment.yml` environment by environment. BTW, this is why *you should manage your environment dependencies explicitly*

Comment: anyway, it seems like you could write a shell script to do this.

Comment: also, I don't think `conda list --export > package-list.txt` lists every package in all of the environments, I think it only does so for your current environment, probably your base environment (which if you use anaconda instead of miniconda may look that way ....)

Comment: Right, I should’ve specified that I’d use that command in an active environment